# C# WPF - Display texts using delays

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, task, delay

**Following case**

Button pressed

Showing Textbox "Successfully ordered"

Delay 2 seconds still showing text

Delay is over and text changes/disappears to "Place your chip"

**Problem:**

Using Thread Sleep it freezes whole UI before showing the Text and just the 2nd text appears after the delay. Interesting is, that a sound I play after changing the text is played but the text isn't shown.

Using Task (async/delay/await) it doesn't wait for the delay and just shows both in a row, so first text for a really short time and then instantly changing to 2nd text.

Using Task (wait) the program crashes.

Using Timer it has the same effect as using Task (async or/and delayed).

Using while (time, 2nd time with +2seconds) now just pushing new time into time and if time is over it's finished, but has the same effect as Thread Sleep - whole UI freezes.

---

Maybe it's interesting to know, that there are timers running in the background the whole time.

I tried many version I found here, but none did work - maybe it's about WPF, so I'm asking right now if someone has a solution for WPF delays.

**Code**

```
        private void SendWithDelay()
        {
          //  close(); // Sets text back to "place your chip" but for here:
          tbPlace.Text = "Place your chip";
        }

        private void changeVisibilityForDelay()
        {
                // called by pressed button
                tbPlace.Text = "Successfully ordered";
                tbPlace.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                Task.Delay(2000).ContinueWith(t => SendWithDelay(), TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
        }
```

Comment: By MCVE @ASh means *Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example* : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry, added one example I tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(using System.Windows.Threading;)
Something like:

```
private void startTimer(){
    Thread timerThread = new Thread(runTimer);
    timerThread.Start();
}

private async void runTimer(){
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => updateScreen()));
}

private void updateScreen(){
    TextBox1.Text = "This is delayed";
}
```

Comment: WPF doesn't seem to have Invoke/MethodInvoker as it doesn't show me any resolutions for usings?

Comment: Sorry - I missed the WPF part. Try System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke in place of Invoke(new MethodInvoker())

Comment: Yep, found the Dispatcher.Invoke too, but now looking to replace the MethodInvoker, seems like I need to use Action delegate.

Comment: It's a "delay" of not even 1second when I use 5000. So it does it still instantly using your code :/

Comment: Okay sorry, it works - another programmer has another place using the "place your chip" text and it overwrites my/your code.

Answer (score 1):

Minimal example with [System.Threading.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx). Also uses [INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) to update changes in UI via [WPF Data Bindings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx).
XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTimerExample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Title="WPF and System.Threading.Timer">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock Text="Text is: " />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
            <TextBlock Text="TimeDiff: " />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TimeDiff}" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
            <Button Name="btnTimerExample" Content="Click to start Timer example"
                    Click="btnTimerExample_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfTimerExample
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        readonly TimeSpan TIMER_DUE_TIME = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
        readonly TimeSpan TIMER_PERIOD = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1);

        DateTimeOffset _timeWhenButtonClicked;
        DateTimeOffset _timeWhenTimerFired;
        Timer _timer;
        string _Text;
        TimeSpan _TimeDiff;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

        public string Text
        {
            get { return _Text; }
            set { _Text = value; PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Text")); }
        }
        public TimeSpan TimeDiff
        {
            get { return _TimeDiff; }
            set { _TimeDiff = value; PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TimeDiff")); }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            DataContext = this;
            Text = "Successfully ordered";
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void btnTimerExample_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Text = "Successfully ordered";
            TimeDiff = TimeSpan.Zero;

            _timeWhenButtonClicked = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
            // If there is no timer
            if (_timer == null) {
                // Create and start timer. 
                // Call TimerHandler just one time after 2 seconds
                _timer = new Timer(TimerHandler, null, TIMER_DUE_TIME, TIMER_PERIOD);
            }
            else // if exist, just restart it
                _timer.Change(TIMER_DUE_TIME, TIMER_PERIOD);
        }
        private void TimerHandler(object state)
        {
            _timeWhenTimerFired = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
            Text = "Place your chip";
            TimeDiff = _timeWhenTimerFired - _timeWhenButtonClicked;
        }
        protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_timer != null)
                _timer.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with DispatcherTimer in this case. Please try the following sample
 add the two one button and one text box.
 
        
        
    
in the code behind add

DispatcherTimer obj = new DispatcherTimer();

```
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox.Text = "Successfully ordered";
        obj.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
        obj.Start();
        obj.Tick += Obj_Tick;
    }

    private void Obj_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox.Text = "Place your chip";
        obj.Stop();
    }
```

Comment: It changes the text instantly to "place your chip" using your code

Comment: Okay sorry, it works - another programmer has another place using the "place your chip" text and it overwrites my/your code.